# Como receber dados de uma API Rest usando Apache Camel

Tags: java, json, apache, rest

E como faço para receber os dados de um servidor *REST* passando uma autorização do tipo *basic* no cabeçalho?

Já tentei de várias formas e não dá certo, e quando testo no *postman*, funciona normalmente.

1. Já tentei da forma simples:

   ```
   from(URL_API_FBITS + "categorias?hierarquia=false")
     .setHeader("Authorization", simple("Basic" + TOKEN))
     .log("${body}").to("file:saida?noop=true");
   ```
2. Convertendo em JSON:

   ```
   from(URL_API_FBITS + "categorias?hierarquia=false")
     .marshal().json(JsonLibrary.Jackson)
     .setHeader(CONTENT_TYPE, simple(APPLICATION_JSON))
     .setHeader("Authorization", simple("Basic " + TOKEN))
     .log("${body}").to("file:saida?noop=true");
   ```

E mesmo assim não deu certo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estava fazendo de forma incorreta, agora estou usando a função .to para realizar a requisição, alterei para:

```
from("timer://foo?fixedRate=true&delay=0&period=10000").setHeader(CONTENT_TYPE, simple(APPLICATION_JSON))
            .setHeader("Authorization", simple("Basic " + TOKEN)).to(URL_API_FBITS + "categorias?hierarquia=false")
            .log("${body}").to("file:saida?noop=true");
```